# Preventing Multiple login instances of same user

Tags: java

I want to prevent multiple login instance of the same user.
Please guide me
As in this code same user can logon multiple times

Below is my code

```
class LoginDemo extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    JButton SUBMIT;
    JPanel panel;
    JLabel lUsername, lPasword;
    final JTextField tUsername,  tPassword;
//    public static TESTPacket test;
    ResultSet _rs = null;
    ConnectionManager _conn;
    Connection connect = null;
    public static Thread dbThread;
    public static Thread rcvThread;
    static byte[] receiveData;
    static int available;
    static InputStream in;
    static DumpData dump;
    static boolean ifFirst;
    DBQueryManager dbq;

    LoginDemo() {

    dbq = new DBQueryManager();
    ifFirst = true;
    lUsername = new JLabel("<HTML><B>Username :<font color='red'>*</font> </B></HTML>");
//        label1.setText();
    tUsername = new JTextField(15);
    //tUsername.setDocument(new JTextFieldLimit(15));
    //tUsername.setText("");

    lPasword= new JLabel("<HTML><B>Password :<font color='red'>*</font> </B></HTML>");
//        label2.setTe/xt();
    tPassword = new JPasswordField(15);
    tPassword.setDocument(new JTextFieldLimit(15));
    tPassword.setText("");
    SUBMIT = new JButton("<HTML><B>LOGIN</B></HTML>");
    SUBMIT.setFocusable(true);

    panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 1, 5, 5));
    JPanel tmp = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
    tmp.add(lUsername);
    tmp.add(tUsername);
    panel.add(tmp);
    tmp = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2));
    tmp.add(lPasword);
    tmp.add(tPassword);
    panel.add(tmp);
    tPassword.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {


    });

     */
    public void ValidateUserPwd() {
    String value1 = tUsername.getText();
    String value2 = tPassword.getText();
    String role = null;
    PreparedStatement pst;
    try {
        if (value1.length() == 0 || value2.length() == 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username and password are mandatory", "Validation", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return;
        }
        connect = _conn.getConnection();
        pst =
            connect.prepareStatement("SELECT USER_PW, sys_user_id, role_id, user_status FROM mydb.gbl_user_mst  WHERE username_id = '" +
            value1 + "' and user_pw='" + value2 + "'");

        _rs = pst.executeQuery();
        _rs.next();
        if (_rs.getString(1).compareTo(value2) != 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Incorrect password", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        tPassword.setText("");
        tPassword.requestFocusInWindow();
        return;
        }
        if (_rs.getInt(4) == 0) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Inactive user", "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        System.exit(0);
        }
        Common.loggedinUser = _rs.getInt(2);
        Common.userRole = _rs.getInt(3);
        InetAddress ownIP = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        String ipaddr = ownIP.getHostAddress();

        Common.sessionID = Integer.parseInt(dbq.fetchSingleData("SELECT fn_login_log(" + Common.loggedinUser + ",'" + ipaddr + "')"));
//            connect.close();
        connect = null;
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LoginDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error in retrieving username and password");
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LoginDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    if (Common.loggedinUser != 0) {

        try {
        this.dispose();
        if (Common.userRole == 1) {
            role = "Active User";
        } else {
            role = "Passive User";
        }

        if (Common.userRole == 1) {
            Common.page.setVisible(false);
            Common.initReceive();
//                    Application1.setThrdSerialConn(new Thread(new SerialConnection(false)));
            new ComPortSelect();
        } else {
            Common.page.setVisible(true);
        }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(LoginDemo.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

    } else {
        System.out.println("enter the valid username and password");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Incorrect username or password", "ERROR", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        tUsername.setText("");
        tPassword.setText("");
        boolean b = tUsername.requestFocusInWindow();
    }
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
    ValidateUserPwd();
    }
}
```

Please tell me
As in this code same user can logon multiple times.

Comment: Nobody is going to read all that code. Please post only the relevant part of it.

Comment: @ amit Now I have cut short my code. Please suggest what to do how to prevent multiple login instance of the same user and where to put that. Please suggest

Comment: put all active logons into `HashSet` and check if user trying to log in already presents in it